# Ratio of a converging sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

We have a sequence determined like this: $a_n=\frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1}+\frac{x}{a_{n-1}})$. This sequence converges to $\sqrt{x}$.

What I'm looking for is $\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}$. Doing some basic algebra you get:

$\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{2(a_{n-1})^2}$

If we look for the limit of the fraction, we get:

$\lim\limits_{n\to_\infty}=\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=\frac{1}{2}$

But shouldn't the limit of a convergent series be:

$\lim\limits_{n\to_\infty}=\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=1?$

Comment: What you wrote is not correct.

Comment: How do you get $\frac12$ as the limit? Note that when $a_{n-1}$ is close to $\sqrt x$, $\frac{x}{2a_{n-1}^2}$ will be close to $\frac12$, not to $0$.

Comment: Thank you, now I see my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If $x=0$ then $a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}}{2}$

and $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

- If $x>0$ then $\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=\sqrt{x}$

and

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{2(\sqrt{x})^2}=1.$$

Comment: I would just like to point out my mistake:$\lim\limits_{n\to_\infty}\frac{1}{(a_{n-1})^2}=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: @Roko This gives the limit $1/2+1/2=1$.